# Error connecting emulator on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, performance, compiler-errors, android-emulator

INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886)
(CL:N/A)

INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\alsye\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\

ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature.

ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.

INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\alsye\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.55.1

I'm expecting to have a detailed solution for my issue as I'm totally beginner to Android studio and I've done re-installing the emulator,restarting the Android studio but the issue didn't solved yet.
help me out . Thank you.